# Trying to return a value from Java and read it in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, json

I have a method in Java that will be returning a JSON object and I am trying to get it to load in to some JavaScript. Here is my code but it is not working:

Java:

```
public JSONObject ticketListener(TicketMessage message) {
    JSONObject listener = new JSONObject();
    try {
        listener.put("Ticket Messenge", message.getText());
        listener.put("Ticket Number", message.getTicketNumber());
        listener.put("Operation", message.getOperation());
        listener.put("UserID", message.getUserID());
        listener.put("Operation Description", message.getOperationDescription());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

JavaScript:

```javascript
$scope.ticketListener = function() {
    var val = $entry(@com.cmcflex.flex.gui.programs.projectmanager.gui.messenger.ticketListener::getValue())();
};
```

Please help.

Comment: Hi Brian and welcome. Before asking a question, ask yourself what other people may require from you to be able to answer at all. We won't just post sample code here.

Comment: Then edit your post with relevant information ;) SO lurkers are skilled in general, but without materials (code) they cannot use their tools (brains)